# Return formatted list from outside module

Tags: python

I feel like I am asking a really stupid basic question, but I'm blacked out and can't get my head around it.

I've got a module that parses a pdf for me, inside the module there is the function that parses the pdf content into a list.

```
def pdfToList(inFile):
    #Do all kinds of stuff with inFile
    list = inFile
```

I am calling pdfToList from a separate file. Because pdfToList parses a file I don't want to call it again when I need the result later in my main program. So I thought I'd return the value with a separate function in my module:

```
def getList():
    return list
```

Needless to say this doesnt work due to scope issues. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show full listing for `pdfToList`?

Comment: make `pdfToList` return `list`? By the way, `list` is not a good name because you're overriding a built-in Python type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```
g_lis t= None
def pdfToList(inFile):
    global g_list
    if g_list is None:
       #Do all kinds of stuff with inFile and set g_list once
       g_list = inFile

    return g_list
```

So in `pdfToList` first check if you have already set the global variable `g_list` and return it else set it, this way you need only one function which you can call again without worrying about loading files again